# Iterate trhough list using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to write script in selenium which will enter each add on certain link and then click button in each of those ads pages. I am having trouble making script determine how to go to one ad and then move to another. The link in question is

So here is the list of the postings:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The script should enter add, hit reply button and then move to another add.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
 Here is script below i have managed to do so far:

```
config = ConfigParser()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/User/Desktop/script/chromedriver.exe")

config.read('settings.ini')
link1 = config['Links']['key1']

for each_section in config.sections():
    for(each_key, each_val) in config.items(each_section):
        driver.get(each_val)
        element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("rows")

        for items in element:
            elem = items.find_elements_by_class_name("result-row")
            elem.click()
```

Comment: There is next previous button exists cant you use that to handle next ads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First capture all ads `href` value in a `list` and then `iterate`  and navigate the each ads page and then click on reply button.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://cnj.craigslist.org/search/mob")
links=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul.rows a.result-title.hdrlnk")))
adslinks=[link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]

for ads in adslinks:
    #navigate each add link
    driver.get(ads)
    #Click on Reply button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.reply-button.js-only"))).click()
```

---

Update the answer with gmail link click.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://cnj.craigslist.org/search/mob")
links=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"ul.rows a.result-title.hdrlnk")))
adslinks=[link.get_attribute("href") for link in links]

for ads in adslinks:

    driver.get(ads)
    #Click on Reply button
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.reply-button.js-only"))).click()
    #Click on Gmail
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.reply-email.gmail"))).click()
    #Pause few seconds to check
    time.sleep(2)
    #move to new window for gmail account
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    #Perform your operation here

    #Close the new window
    driver.close()
    # Pause few seconds to check
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be working very well. Can you just please help me target gmail icon in reply button section? http://prntscr.com/s0rx7u
Thank you very much!

Comment: Shall I come back tomorrow morning?

Comment: @ArkanKalu : Check the updated answer with gmail link click.If this resolved your question feel free to accept this as an answer.Thanks.